# How to sum the values in a specific column of a .txt file starting at row 2

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to sum all of the values under the column "Packets" obviously I want just the integers and not the string "Packets" so it would have to start at row 2. The output should equal 9 in this case. For the case of Packets its column id is [7].

CODE:

```
import os
from scipy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import socket

with open('/Users/rojeliomaestas/Desktop/nettest2.txt') as infile:
    next(infile)
    for line in infile:


        print("------------------------------------------------")
        print("Date:",line.split()[0])
        print("Time:",line.split()[1])
        print("Protocol:",line.split()[3])
        print("Packets:",line.split()[7])
        print("From IP:",line.split()[4])
        print("To IP:",line.split()[6])
        print("------------------------------------------------")


        data = open('/Users/rojeliomaestas/Desktop/nettest2.txt').read()


    print ("Total UDP protocols are:", data.count('UDP'))        
   # if 'UDP':    
    #    print ("~ Total ICMP packets are:", data.count(line.split()[7]))

    print ("\nTotal TCP protocols are:", data.count('TCP'))
   # if 'TCP':    
    #    print ("~ Total TCP packets are:", data.count(line.split()[7]))        

    print ("\nTotal ICMP protocols are:", data.count('ICMP'))

   # if 'ICMP':    
    #   print ("~ Total ICMP packets are:", data.count(line.split()[7]))

    val = (data.count('UDP') + data.count('TCP') + data.count('ICMP'))

    print("\nTotal protocols in the time frame",line.split()[1],"is:",val,"protocols.")





    udp = (data.count('UDP'))
    tcp = (data.count('TCP'))
    icmp = (data.count('ICMP'))


    figure(1)

    ax = plot.subplot(111)

    ax.bar(1,udp,width=0.2,align='center')
    ax.bar(2,tcp,width=0.2,align='center')
    ax.bar(3,icmp,width=0.2,align='center')
    ax.set_xticklabels(['0', 'UDP', '', 'TCP', '', 'ICMP'])
    xlabel("This graph shows amount of protocols used")
    ylabel("Number of times used")


print("\nThe amount of times The domain Northern New Mexico college was accessed is:", data.count('205.166.231')) 



domainName = socket.gethostbyaddr(line.split()[4].rsplit(':', 1)[0])[0]
if 'google' in domainName:                                  

    total = 0

with open('/Users/rojeliomaestas/Desktop/nettest2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        finded = line.find('8.8.8.8')
        if finded != -1 and finded != 0:
            total += 1

print("\nThe domain Google.com occurs", total,"times.")



s1 = line.split()[4][line.split()[4].find(":")+1:]  
port1 = int(s1)

portName = socket.getservbyport(port1)
if 'http' in portName:
    print("\nProtocol for port 80: HTTP")
```

[Content of text file]

```
Date first seen          Duration Proto      Src IP Addr:Port          Dst IP Addr:Port   Packets    Bytes Flows
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 UDP            8.8.8.8:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929        1      275     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 UDP            8.8.8.8:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929        1      275     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 UDP            8.8.8.8:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929        1      275     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 TCP            8.8.8.8:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929        1      275     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 TCP            8.8.8.8:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929        1      275     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 TCP            8.8.8.8:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929        1      275     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 TCP            8.8.8.8:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929        1      275     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 ICMP           8.8.8.8:23 ->     205.166.231.250:49929        1      275     1
2017-04-02 12:08:32.079     9.298 ICMP           8.8.8.8:23 ->     205.166.231.250:49929        1      275     1
```

[Content of text file]

Comment: Pls include code in your question as text

Comment: Code is up, I believe a moderator edited.

Comment: Do you like the provided answers, or do you need further assistance?

Comment: None of the answers are producing what I need, yes further assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: WHAT are you missing? From what I can see both answers provide what you asked for.

Comment: While editing you can select text and then use the button {} above to make it a code snippet - it will get 4 spaces in front of every line and appear grey ...

Comment: Got it! Thanks the content is posted.

Comment: Eager to hear how did it come that you have got **1** instead of **9**  ?

Comment: Honestly I have no clue, I do get 9 now, however it prints every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Take care that the print statement is not indented ... so it prints only once. In Python indentation is very important! If you indent the print statement it belongs to the loop, if you unindent it it doesn't belong to the loop, ok? In your text editor has the indentation of each line be exactly as in the text you can copy/paste from the grey code snippet box.

Comment: OH duh I knew that.. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You are welcome :) . Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum = 0
for line in infile:
    columns = line.split() # do it once per line
    sum = sum + int(columns[7])
    ...

print(sum)
```

Here the full code printing `9` :

```
with open('gettingSum_Cg.txt') as infile:
    next(infile)
    sum = 0
    for line in infile:
        columns = line.split() # do it once per line
        sum = sum + int(columns[7])

print(sum)
```

and here the content of `gettingSum_Cg.txt`:

```
Date first seen         Duration Proto      Src       IP Addr:Port Dst IP Addr:Port       Packets Bytes Flows 
2014-04-02 12:08:32.079    9.298 UDP        8.8.8.8.:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929      1     275    1
2014-04-02 12:08:32.079    9.298 UDP        8.8.8.8.:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929      1     275    1
2014-04-02 12:08:32.079    9.298 UDP        8.8.8.8.:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929      1     275    1
2014-04-02 12:08:32.079    9.298 UDP        8.8.8.8.:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929      1     275    1
2014-04-02 12:08:32.079    9.298 UDP        8.8.8.8.:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929      1     275    1
2014-04-02 12:08:32.079    9.298 UDP        8.8.8.8.:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929      1     275    1
2014-04-02 12:08:32.079    9.298 UDP        8.8.8.8.:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929      1     275    1
2014-04-02 12:08:32.079    9.298 UDP        8.8.8.8.:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929      1     275    1
2014-04-02 12:08:32.079    9.298 UDP        8.8.8.8.:80 ->     205.166.231.250:49929      1     275    1
```

The code when run prints **9** ...

Comment: What does it mean "Python doesn't like this?" Python is not a human ... The `print(sum)` should print `9` ... the `"..."` represent the other code in your loop.

Comment: Just copy/paste the content of your file into your question so that I can provide you with the complete code giving the evidence that my code prints the right result. (you know that you can edit your question at any time?)

Comment: Okay Instead of an error now I get 1.. same result as what the other guy posted.. I will add the content to the end of the post..

Answer (score 1):

You are very near to your goal. Just add every packet to a variable as following.

```
packets = 0
infile = open('E:\sample.txt')
for line in infile.readlines()[1:]
    packets += int(line.split()[7]) # As, packet column in 5th
print("Packets:"+str(packets))
infile.close()
```

It will let you print all packets. Working with python 2.7

Hope, it helps!

Comment: OP has already elegantly taken in account in his code that he has to skip the first line in the file. What is the enumerating you use good for??? Packets are in column 7 not 5 ...

Comment: Ah yes! actually! i was referencing as column name instead of spacing. thankks @claudio nice catch!

Comment: Maybe you could take out the not necessary enumeration out of the loop and skip checking for the first line, because it was already done in the code the author of the question provided?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this gives me an output of 1 it need to be 9.

Comment: I got an output of 0. I have added the content of the txt file to the end of my post if you would like to try and run it.

Comment: That code is working fine now. I was reading file incorrectly. Sry for inconvenience. Hope it works for you now!